Recording Start Failed - File Not Created Error
Question:
I am encountering an issue with OpenVidu where the recording fails to start. I'm using OpenVidu version 2.30.0 and running it in a Docker container. The recording starts correctly for a session but fails with the following error:
[ERROR] 2024-06-11 05:50:43,255 [http-nio-0.0.0.0-4443-exec-2] io.openvidu.server.recording.service.RecordingService - Recording start failed for session SessionA: Couldn't initialize recording container. Error: File /opt/openvidu/recordings/SessionA~9/SessionA~9.mp4 does not exist and hasn't been created in 30 seconds
[INFO] 2024-06-11 05:50:43,276 [http-nio-0.0.0.0-4443-exec-2] io.openvidu.server.recording.service.RecordingService - Sealed recording metadata file at /opt/openvidu/recordings/SessionA~9/.recording.SessionA~9 with status [failed]
[INFO] 2024-06-11 05:50:43,276 [http-nio-0.0.0.0-4443-exec-2] io.openvidu.server.recording.service.ComposedRecordingService - Stopping composed (video + audio) recording SessionA~9 of session SessionA. Reason: null


Here are the details of my setup:

Docker Command:
docker run -p 4443:4443 --rm \
    -e OPENVIDU_SECRET=MY_SECRET \
    -e OPENVIDU_RECORDING=true \
    -e OPENVIDU_RECORDING_PATH=/opt/openvidu/recordings \
    -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
    -v /opt/openvidu/recordings:/opt/openvidu/recordings \
openvidu/openvidu-dev:2.30.0



Spring Boot Controller Code:
package com.aide.backend;

import io.openvidu.java.client.*;
import jakarta.annotation.PostConstruct;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.Map;

@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
@RestController
public class MediaServerController {

    @Value("${OPENVIDU_URL}")
    private String OPENVIDU_URL;

    @Value("${OPENVIDU_SECRET}")
    private String OPENVIDU_SECRET;

    private OpenVidu openvidu;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        this.openvidu = new OpenVidu(OPENVIDU_URL, OPENVIDU_SECRET);
    }

    @PostMapping("/api/sessions")
    public ResponseEntity<String> initializeSession(@RequestBody(required = false) Map<String, Object> params)
            throws OpenViduJavaClientException, OpenViduHttpException {
        SessionProperties properties = SessionProperties.fromJson(params).build();
        Session session = openvidu.createSession(properties);
        System.out.println(session.getSessionId());
        return new ResponseEntity<>(session.getSessionId(), HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @PostMapping("/api/sessions/{sessionId}/connections")
    public ResponseEntity<String> createConnection(@PathVariable("sessionId") String sessionId,
                                                   @RequestBody(required = false) Map<String, Object> params)
            throws OpenViduJavaClientException, OpenViduHttpException {
        Session session = openvidu.getActiveSession(sessionId);
        if (session == null) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }
        ConnectionProperties properties = ConnectionProperties.fromJson(params).build();
        Connection connection = session.createConnection(properties);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(connection.getToken(), HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @PostMapping("/start/{sessionId}")
    public ResponseEntity<Void> startRecording(@PathVariable("sessionId") String sessionId,
                                               @RequestBody(required = false) Map<String, Object> params)
            throws OpenViduJavaClientException, OpenViduHttpException {

        RecordingProperties properties = new RecordingProperties.Builder()
                .outputMode(Recording.OutputMode.COMPOSED)
                .hasAudio(true)
                .hasVideo(true)
                .build();

        final Recording recording = openvidu.startRecording(sessionId, properties);
        System.out.println("recording ID: " + recording.getId());
        return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
    }

    @PostMapping("/stop/{sessionId}")
    public ResponseEntity<Void> recoding2(@PathVariable("sessionId") String sessionId,
                                          @RequestBody(required = false) Map<String, Object> params)
            throws OpenViduJavaClientException, OpenViduHttpException {

        final Recording recording1 = openvidu.stopRecording(sessionId);
        System.out.println(recording1.getUrl());
        return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
    }
}




Steps I've Taken:

Ensured that Docker volumes are correctly mounted and the OpenVidu server has write access to the recording path.
Checked that the OpenVidu server is running and sessions can be created without issues.
Verified that the OPENVIDU_RECORDING_PATH is correctly set and accessible.

Observations:

The recording initialization fails because the expected recording file is not created within 30 seconds.
I tried running the same setup with previous versions (e.g., 2.5.0), and the recording worked fine without this timeout issue.

Additional Information:
I also checked the OpenVidu documentation for relevant configurations but didn't find a solution.
Questions:

How can I prevent the recording initialization from failing due to the file not being created in time?
Are there any additional configurations or steps required to ensure the recording starts successfully?

Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
........................
